# TypeScript extend all value types of an interface / type

Tags: typescript, types, interface, extend

Given an interface of known keys and values, is it possible to tell TypeScript that I want to have a type that has all the same keys of my original interface with value types extended via union of the original type and another type. Pseudo (sadly non-functional) TypeScript code that describes the desired behaviour:

```
type FancyCSSObject = { [key: keyof CSSObject]: CSSObject[key] | OtherType };
```

The above is not valid TypeScript, so my question is, how to express this in valid TypeScript code?

Answer (score 2):

Before I finished posting this, I realised the solution to this problem, however seeing that it's sort of a corner-case that's not documented in its entirety, I will share my solution, in case someone else needs this:

```
type FancyCSSObject = {
  [key in keyof CSSObject]: CSSObject[key] | OtherType;
};
```

I was close to the solution. I hope this helps someone.